# Insert call a method and insert values

Tags: go

I have this working in another programming language, creating a url to reverse geocode a location. I am new to Go and I am slowly working building up the script.

I have the method Geofunction(x,y) with the two variables x & y 
From another method I call the above method and supply the values to the variables.

I just can't get it to work as expected.

Could someone point me to where to help me find the answer give me some help on this please.

I have a working coy in Python, as I learn Go I am translating scripts  understand.

I have made changes to allow certain variable to accessible to the other functions. I need to understand if the method called with be able to access the variable values.

````
package main

import "fmt"

var Location1x, Location1y string
var Location1 string
var rev_geo string

func Geofunction(x, y) {
    var str1 string = "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key="
    var str2 string = "**********************"  //API Key
    var str3 string = x // '48.853106'
    var str4 string = "&lon="
    var str5 string = y // '2.384202'
    var str6 string = "&format=json"
    var rev_geo string = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5 + str6

    return rev_geo
}

func Locator() {
    Location1x, Location1y = "48.853106", "2.384202"
    Location1 = Geofunction(Location1x, Location1y)
}

func main() {
    Locator()
    fmt.Println(Location1)
}```

Expected:
A string of a URL is printed.

The three errors are: 
main.go:9:18: undefined: x
main.go:9:21: undefined: y
Geofunction(Location1x, Location1y) used as value


Once I get the above sorted, I will then reuse the method to produce multiple strings in an API test that confirms specific data in the json files returned from the server
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few pieces.

1. The types for `x` and `y` in the function definition are missing. Since the are both `string`s, the type can be defined simultaneously.
2. The function `GeoFunction` is missing a return type, which should be `string`

Go is quite strict about syntax and structure, unlike Python - I would strongly suggest completing the the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/) before transpiling any code, it will make things a lot smoother for you.

Try something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var Location1x, Location1y string
var Location1 string
var rev_geo string

func Geofunction(x, y string) string {
    var str1 string = "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key="
    var str2 string = "**********************"  //API Key
    var str3 string = x // '48.853106'
    var str4 string = "&lon="
    var str5 string = y // '2.384202'
    var str6 string = "&format=json"
    var rev_geo string = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5 + str6

    return rev_geo
}

func Locator() {
    Location1x, Location1y = "48.853106", "2.384202"
    Location1 = Geofunction(Location1x, Location1y)
}

func main() {
    Locator()
    fmt.Println(Location1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ragav Sood this has complete the issue I had with Geofunction seen as a value and the url prints out.

Answer (score -1):

Your method definition is wrong overe here, given go is a statically typed language your function definitions should have the type of the parameters which it takes alongside the parameter names

```
package main

import "fmt"

var Location1x, Location1y string
var Location1 string
var rev_geo string

func Geofunction(x string, y string) {
var str1 string = "https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key="
var str2 string = "**********************"  //API Key
var str3 string = x // '48.853106'
var str4 string = "&lon="
var str5 string = y // '2.384202'
var str6 string = "&format=json"
var rev_geo string = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5 + str6

return rev_geo
}

func Locator() {
Location1x, Location1y = "48.853106", "2.384202"
Location1 = Geofunction(Location1x, Location1y)
}

func main() {
Locator()
fmt.Println(Location1)
}
```

This should basically work, but a better approach to this would be to use a string builder instead of appending strings. That’s more efficient

Comment: This has resolved this part of my issue. I will look at replacing with a string Builder once I get a complete running script.

Comment: As my reputation is less than 15. Upvotes are hidden from me